# Internal speaker is not muted with plugged-in headphones

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-10.04, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linux speakers and headphones play together](https://superuser.com/questions/218154/linux-speakers-and-headphones-play-together)

I recently bought some headphones for my laptop (HP/Compaq nc4200). To my disappointment the internal speaker is not muted when I plug in the headphones. I googled around but didn't find a solution so far. Some recommended turn down volume. This work in an environment with background noise, but not in trains etc. So do you know of some way to mute them (with plugged in headphones)? If it does matter, the laptop runs Ubuntu 10.04.